# Passing property from map function to component in array results in property inside { }

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having a strange issue, first component like so:

```
const AccountsBar = () => {
    const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        listAccountsWorker()
            .then(res => {
                for (const item of res) {
                    console.log(item.snapshot.avatar_url);
                    // outputs https://someurl.com
                }
                setAccounts(res);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="account-bar-container">
            {accounts.map(item => (
                <AccountAvatar
                    key={item._id} 
                    avatarURl={item.snapshot.avatar_url}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AccountsBar;
```

When I pass the avatarURL into the component I get an `undefined` error. I logged the prop in that component and it seems to be passing `{avatarURl: "https://someurl.com"}` instead of `avatarURL`:

```
const AccountAvatar = avatarURl => {
    console.log(account);
    // outputs {avatarURl: "https://someurl.com"}
    return (
        <Image src={avatarURl} className="account-avatar rounded-circle" />
    );
};

AccountAvatar.propTypes = {
    avatarURl: PropTypes.string
};

export default AccountAvatar;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter for a functional component is props and so what you're seeing is actually the [props object](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). You probably meant to destructure it like so:

```js
const AccountAvatar = ({ avatarURl }) => {   
    return (
        <Image src={avatarURl} className="account-avatar rounded-circle" />
    );
};

AccountAvatar.propTypes = {
    avatarURl: PropTypes.string
};

export default AccountAvatar;
```

Comment: It's very important to be careful about the brackets in react. when you receive without the brackets it's basically receiving all the props as a bundle just with a different name 'avatarURl' . That's why it was an object.

Comment: Missed this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `account` that you are logging in your second snippet ? is it `avatarURl` ? if so then you you just need to do `<Image src={account.avatarURl} .../>`